# project with React, Rest API with python, Sql database

Tags: python, reactjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a project for school and they want me to create schedule app with:

- React as Frontend
- Rest API with python(i chose django rest framework)
- SQL database (i chose SQLite as default of django but can change to PostgreSQL)

But i have no idea to how to connect them to each other,
i am all open to new ideas please help me.

My main question is; Do i have to use fetch method to get the data in react or just django functions

Thank you.

Comment: Django REST is the backend that stores user data and holds business logic. React is the front end that deals with the UI. You can use Axios to connect react UI with Django. You can make a call to Django REST API from react UI that involves(get/post/put..). and get the required data. Make sure you have basic implementation knowledge on both before starting.

Comment: Thank you for  your comment, axios or fetch doing same job so i think i need to do crud operations with that on front end. Is it a must? what if i do crud operations with just django without fetch or axios

Comment: Data modification in database should be done in django that includes CURD but some data mainpulation is done based on the user demand, those information should be sent from React to django. You should go through the tutorial of django REST to get an idea on how it works. Suppose if you have a get request view in django,  that pulls data from certain model, then you need to send get request from react to django REST API.